# Using a suppression file with Dr.Memory

Tags: dr-memory

I've had a look at [the Dr. Memory documentation on suppressing errors](http://www.drmemory.org/docs/page_suppress.html)

but am still unclear on the finer points of using a suppression file. For example, if I use the following suppression file:

```
LEAK
name=Error #3 (ICU errors)
sbicuuc53_32.dll!*
```

will any error with a stack trace that contains `sbicuuc53_32.dll` *anywhere* be ignored? Or will it only ignore errors where `sbicuuc53_32.dll` appears at the top of the stack frame? I'm confused because it seems that whitelisted/blacklisted dlls cause errors to be ignored only if the DLL in question appears at the top of the stack trace (see http://www.drmemory.org/docs/page_running.html#sec_potential_errors).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but the documentation says: `A "*" matches any number of characters of any kind.`.  Therefore, I think a suppression like

```
UNINITIALIZED READ
name=Error #1 (ICU errors)
sbicuuc53_32.dll!*
```

should suppress any errors that have a call stack whose top frame starts
with sbicuuc53_32.dll!.